# how much grass does a sheep eat in square meters per day?

Tags: zoology

I want to buy some sheeps in order to eat my garden's grass.

How much grass does a sheep eat each day ??

Comment: What species of sheep? How old? In what climate?

Comment: This: http://www.urbanshepherds.com might have the answer.

Comment: @sheep agree with terdon, some more detail would be nice.